# How to add Bulma page loader extension as Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma

I'm trying to set up `page-loader` element which is Bulma-extension in a Vue project. Is there a way to add `page-loader` as a Vue `component`?

I have tried to import `page-loader.min.js` and use it but doesn't work at all.

```html
<template>
    <div class="steps">
        <div class="step-marker">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bulmaSteps } from 'bulma-extensions/dist/js/bulma-extensions.min';

export default {
    name: "TestingStep",
    mounted: function() {
        this.steps = bulmaSteps.attach();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            steps: [],
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import CSS file in the script section and it works like a charm.

`import 'bulma-extensions/bulma-steps/dist/css/bulma-steps.min.css';`

Comment: why is this done in the `<script>` section and not in the `<styles lang="scss">` section? Is it possible to do in the `<styles lang="scss">` section (for example `@import '~bulma-calendar'` as described here https://wikiki.github.io/#integration )?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you trying to achieve.

**PageLoader.vue**

```html
    <template>
        <div class="pageloader">
          <span class="title">Pageloader</span>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import 'bulma-extensions/bulma-pageloader/dist/css/bulma-pageloader.min.css';
    </script>
```

And import the component it your desirable vue file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I imported the `bulma-steps` package:

```html
<template>
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step-marker">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import StepsWizard from "bulma-steps/dist/js/bulma-steps.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  mounted() {
    new StepsWizard(document.querySelector(".steps"));
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "~bulma-steps/dist/css/bulma-steps.min.css";
</style>
```

If wanting to use `.attach()`, it should be done within `mounted()`.